# El resultado de una función entry (entrada de texto) no se muestra en una ventana Toplevel en tkinter

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

estoy iniciando con la POO así que probablemente mi duda no sea muy difícil de resolver, sin embargo, aún no logro solucionarlo. Tengo un código que funciona como predictor de texto obtenido de aquí https://github.com/Neil-Brown/tkPredictiveEntry/blob/master/entry.py y al probarlo funciona mostrando el cuadro entry (cuadro de texto) en la ventana principal tal como debería pasar, lo que quiero hacer es que el cuadro entry se muestre en una ventana de Toplevel, lo cual es sencillo utilizando el método Entry preestablecido, sin embargo al utilizar el código descrito en el link y mandando a llamar a Entry, en los argumentos coloco la ventana Toplevel y sigue colocando el cuadro de texto en la ventana principal, así como si ignorara esa línea, supuse que el problema estaba en el programa entry.py en la línea 24 (self.master=window), sin embargo, aún modificando esa línea no cambia nada. Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda o comentario y adjunto los dos códigos tanto entry.py como el de prueba.

prueba.py

```
import tkinter as tk

from entry import Entry

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.newWindow=tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.entry = Entry(window=self.newWindow,
                             inactive_foreground="grey",
                             active_foreground="black",
                             font=("Arial", 20),
                             text="Display message",
                             predictive_list = [
                                                "Michael Jackson",
                                                "George Michael",
                                                "Tom Cruise",
                             ]

        )
        self.entry.pack(fill=None, expand=False)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

---

entry.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class Entry(tk.Text):
    """ Custom Entry widget that provides predictive text from a list of terms passed in as a kwarg"""
    def __init__(self,window,
                 text="Search",
                 font=("Arial", 12),
                 inactive_foreground="grey",
                 active_foreground="black",
                 width=15,
                 height=1,
                 predictive_list=()
    ):
        tk.Text.__init__(self)
        """ Sets the keyword parameters as attributes and bind the relevant keys to metods."""

        self.master= window  #línea 24
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.inactive_foreground = inactive_foreground
        self.active_foreground = active_foreground

        self.predictive_list = sorted(predictive_list)

        self.configure(font=self.font, width=width, height=height)
        self.configure(tabs=(1,))

        self.tag_configure("predictive", foreground=self.inactive_foreground)
        self.tag_configure("normal", foreground=self.active_foreground)

        self.bindtags(('Text', 'post-class-bindings', '.', 'all'))

        self.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<FocusIn>", lambda event: self.focus_in())
        self.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<FocusOut>", lambda event: self.focus_out())
        self.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<KeyPress>", lambda event: self.input())
        self.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<Right>", lambda event: self.autofill())
        self.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<Left>", lambda event: self.move_left())
        self.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<Delete>", lambda event: self.delete_called())
        self.bind_class("post-class-bindings", "<BackSpace>", lambda event: self.delete_called())

        self.focus_out()

    def focus_out(self):
        """ Put the default text into the entry if entry is equal and entry aws no focus"""
        if self.get("1.0", "end-1c") == "":
            self.configure(font=self.font, foreground=self.inactive_foreground)
            self.insert("1.0", self.text)

    def focus_in(self):
        """ Delete default text when entry gets focus"""
        if self.get("1.0", "end-1c") == self.text:
            self.delete("1.0", "end-1c")
            self.configure(font=self.font, foreground=self.active_foreground)

    def input(self):
        """ Called when a key is pressed. Calls relevent methods."""
        self.reduce_tag()
        user_txt = self.get_user_text()
        pred_txt = self.get_predictive_text(user_txt)
        if not pred_txt:
            self.remove_predictive_text()
            return
        self.insert_txt(user_txt, pred_txt)

    def insert_txt(self, user_txt, pred_txt):
        """ Delete entry contents and refill with user text but predictive text if available"""
        self.delete("1.0", "end-1c")
        self.insert("1.0", user_txt + pred_txt)
        self.mark_set("insert", "1.{}".format(len(user_txt)))
        self.tag_add("predictive", "insert", "end-1c")

    def remove_predictive_text(self):
        """ Clear entry of text and predictive tag"""
        self.tag_remove("predictive", "1.0", "end-1c")
        self.delete("insert", "end-1c")

    def reduce_tag(self):
        """ Remove the start of the predictive tag range"""
        if self.tag_ranges("predictive"):
            self.tag_remove("predictive", self.tag_ranges("predictive")[0])

    def get_user_text(self):
        """ Return range of user inputed text"""
        if self.tag_ranges("predictive"):
            end = "{}".format(self.tag_ranges("predictive")[0].string)
        else:
            end = "end"
        return self.get("1.0", end+"-1c")

    def get_predictive_text(self, txt):
        """ Return predicitve text if iser input matches list items"""
        for item in self.predictive_list:
            if item.lower().startswith(txt.lower()):
                return item[len(txt):]
        return None

    def move_left(self):
        """ Called when left cursor is pressed. Move one space left."""
        self.mark_set("insert", "insert")

    def autofill(self):
        """ Called on the right cursor being pressed.
        Fill entry with rest of predictive text in normal foreground color"""
        self.tag_remove("predictive", "1.0", "end-1c")
        self.tag_add("normal", "1.0", "end-1c")
        self.mark_set("insert", "end-1c")

    def delete_called(self):
        """ Called when backspace is pressed.
            Delete predictive text if cursor is at "1.0"""
        if self.tag_ranges("predictive") and self.tag_ranges("predictive")[0].string == "1.0":
            self.tag_remove("predictive", "1.0", "end-1c")
        self.input()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay un error importante que no es tuyo, sino del código original y es la linea:

```
tk.Text.__init__(self)
```

esto llama al inicializador del padre de la clase `Entry` (`tkinter.Text`) pero **no le pasa la referencia al widget padre** (en tu caso `window`). Al no hacerlo, el widget no inicializa correctamente y se queda sin padre asignado. Cuando un widget no se le asigna padre, por defecto es la instancia de tkinter.Tk y pack/grid/place psocionan en ella (que es lo que te pasa).

Cambia esa línea por:

```
tk.Text.__init__(self, window)
```

o mejor, usa `super`, que los tiempos han cambiado :)

```
super().__init__(window)
```

y todo debe ir correctamente. La línea `self.master = window` puedes quitarla, ya se encarga el inicializador del padre de asignar al atributo `master` lo que debe.